# Display form fields using loop in twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I am working on a form that collects number of credit card loans a user has, a person can add as many credit card fields as he desires so the problem I am having is how to render the form fields when a user has multiple entries

Here is the twig dump and as you can see in this example user has 2 entries and I would like to use loop to render these fields.

[image]

At present the fields look like this

[image]

That's because I am using `{{ form_rest(form) }}` to dump the fields

While checking the source of the creditcard fields this is what i see

```
<div>                
        <label class="required">0</label>
        <div id="examplebundle_debt_creditcards_0">
            <div>
                <label for="examplebundle_debt_creditcards_0_balance" class="required">Balance</label>
                <input type="number" id="examplebundle_debt_creditcards_0_balance" name="examplebundle_debt[creditcards][0][balance]" required="required" value="3000">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="examplebundle_debt_creditcards_0_amountDue" class="required">Amount due</label>
                <input type="number" id="examplebundle_debt_creditcards_0_amountDue" name="examplebundle_debt[creditcards][0][amountDue]" required="required" value="300">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="examplebundle_debt_creditcards_0_interestRate" class="required">Interest rate</label>
                <input type="number" id="examplebundle_debt_creditcards_0_interestRate" name="examplebundle_debt[creditcards][0][interestRate]" required="required" value="3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So my question is, how can i use a loop to display the correct number of creditcard related fields dynamically?

Comment: What about : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html ?

Comment: How on earth did I miss that, I had the same page open and I was actually following that :) thanks.. i need a break

Comment: No problem ;) good luck

Comment: you should post this as an answer